# Display Data from a database in a listview with a arrayadapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, android-arrayadapter

Hy guys!

I've got a problem. My app should display all routes in a listview. But there is something wrong with the arrayadapter. If i try my arrayadapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<DefineRoute> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DefineRoute>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,verbindungen.getVerbindungen());
```

it works, but it only display the objectname of DefineRoute and i wanna display the output of the cursor.
Ithink i should try:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,verbindungen.getVerbindungen());
```

But here comes the error: Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter

Here is my Acticity:

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.planausgabelayout);

            //Aufruf der TextViews
            TextView txtStart = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAusgabeStart);
            TextView txtZiel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAusgabeZiel);
            TextView txtZeit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAusgabeZeit);


            intent = getIntent();

            txtStart.setText(intent.getStringExtra("StartHaltestelle"));
            txtZiel.setText(intent.getStringExtra("ZielHaltestelle"));
            txtZeit.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Zeit"));

            getRoute();
        }

        public void getRoute() {
            lvList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvList);
            Verbindungen verbindungen = new Verbindungen(this);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,verbindungen.getVerbindungen());

            lvList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Here is my Activity Define Route:

```
public class DefineRoute {
    private String abfahrtszeit;
    private String ankunftszeit;
    private String dauer;
    private String umstieg;

    public DefineRoute(String abfahrtszeit, String ankunftszeit, String dauer, String umstieg)
    {
        this.abfahrtszeit = getAbfahrtszeit();
        this.ankunftszeit = getAnkunftszeit();
        this.dauer = getDauer();
        this.umstieg = getUmstieg();
    }

    public String getAbfahrtszeit() {
        return abfahrtszeit;
    }

    public String getAnkunftszeit() {
        return  ankunftszeit;
    }

    public String getDauer() {
        return dauer;
    }

    public String getUmstieg() {
        return umstieg;
    }
}
```

Here is my Activity Verbindungen:

```
public class Verbindungen {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    LinkedList<DefineRoute> route;
    DefineRoute[] routeArray;
    Context context;

    DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = null;

    public Verbindungen(Context context) {
        route = new LinkedList<DefineRoute>();
        this.context = context;
        myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public DefineRoute[] getVerbindungen() {

        try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }

        db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        // Alle Daten der Datenbank abrufen mithilfe eines Cursors
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT strftime('%H:%M', f.abfahrt) AS Abfahrt," +
                "strftime('%H:%M', f.ankunft) AS Ankunft," +
                "strftime('%H:%M', strftime('%s',f.ankunft)- strftime('%s',f.abfahrt), 'unixepoch') AS Dauer," +
                "r.name AS Route," +
                "count(u.fahrt_id) AS Umstiege " +
                "FROM scotty_fahrt f " +
                "JOIN scotty_haltestelle start ON f.start_id = start.id " +
                "JOIN scotty_haltestelle ziel ON f.ziel_id = ziel.id " +
                "JOIN scotty_route r ON f.route_id = r.id " +
                "LEFT OUTER JOIN scotty_umstiegsstelle u ON f.id = u.fahrt_id " +
                "WHERE start.name = 'Linz/Donau Hbf (Busterminal)' " +
                "AND ziel.name = 'Neufelden Busterminal (Schulzentrum)' " +
                "GROUP BY u.fahrt_id",null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int i=0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            //in this string we get the record for each row from the column "name"
            i++;
        }
        routeArray = new DefineRoute[i];
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int k =0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            routeArray[k] = new DefineRoute(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3));
            k++;

        }
        //here we close the cursor because we do not longer need it
        //}
        cursor.close();
        myDbHelper.close();

        return routeArray;

    }
```

please help me.

Now i am creating a ArrayAdapter class where i define my ouput in the listview with:

```
public class RouteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DefineRoute>{
    Activity context;
    DefineRoute[] defineroute;

    public RouteAdapter(Activity context, DefineRoute[] defineroute){
        super(context, R.layout.layoutausgabe, defineroute);
        this.defineroute = defineroute;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutausgabe,null);
        TextView txZeit = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txZeit);
        TextView txDauer = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txDauer);
        TextView txUmstieg = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txUmstieg);

        DefineRoute defineRoute = defineroute[position];

        txZeit.setText(defineRoute.getAbfahrtszeit() + " - " + defineRoute.getAnkunftszeit());
        txDauer.setText(defineRoute.getDauer());
        txUmstieg.setText(defineRoute.getUmstieg());
        return row;
    }
}
```

How should i continue?
and what should my adapter look like?

Comment: first use international language when programming, not Deutsch, 

second use CursorAdapter based class for example SimpleCursorAdaptet

Comment: i actually create a class for the arrayadapter

Comment: its waste of time and mem: when you have a Cursor then SimpleCursorAdapter is the obvious choice

Comment: Yeah but i need a specific layout in the listview not the standrt

Comment: SCA doesnt use any std layout

Comment: could you give me an example how it should be look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayAdapter<String>` is type of `String` so pass `String` list to it's constructor instead of `verbindungen.getVerbindungen()` list of objects.

Comment: can you please help me i don't know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

ArrarAdapter < T > is any type of class you can use

in your case ArrayAdapter so you need override toString method of DefineRoute class

in your case

```
 @Override
     public String toString() {
     return ankunftszeit+" "+ankunftszeit;
//or what ever you want to displat
     }
```

or there is other Solution is Create your Own adapter extending by BaseAdapter Class.

Comment: Yeah i tried it and i've made a class routeAdapter were i define a layout for my adapter but what now please help me. In the other classes everthing is the same as before but i have add this Activity:

Comment: public class RouteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DefineRoute>{
        Activity context;
        DefineRoute[] defineroute;
    
        public RouteAdapter(Activity context, DefineRoute[] defineroute){
            super(context, R.layout.layoutausgabe, defineroute);
            this.defineroute = defineroute;
            this.context = context;
        }
    
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

Comment: what problem you are facing..?

Comment: ther is a problem at the array adapter. Because he is Arrayadapter<string> and this didn't work but i need it because i wanna display string elemts(TextViews)